# How to put a job on wait in powershell

Tags: powershell

HI every one I Have the following scripts which i am working on but not sure how to put a wait for a zip to finish and than move on to the next block of code. following are the two scripts which i am using. The first script is a backup script which is calling another script for zipping

```
$Date = Get-Date

$folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")

$backup_folder_name = 'c:\Russia\' + $folder_date
$V3_folder_name = 'C:\121RussiaScaled\products'
$Admin_folder_name = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\admin'
$Tablet_folder_name = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tabl'
$Service_folder_name = 'C:\Russia\dll'


if (!(Test-Path -path $backup_folder_name)) {
New-Item $backup_folder_name -type directory
} # if (!(Test-Path -path D:Data))

if ((Test-Path -path $V3_folder_name)) {

Start-job -scriptblock {gi $V3_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1    
$backup_folder_name\V3.zip $_} 

Wait-job -Id $Job.Id

}

if ((Test-Path -path $Service_folder_name)) {
$Job = Start-job -scriptblock {gi $Service_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1   
$backup_folder_name\Services.zip $_} 

Wait-job -Id $Job.Id


}

if ((Test-Path -path $Admin_folder_name)) {
$Job = Start-job -scriptblock {gi $Admin_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1    
$backup_folder_name\admin.zip $_} 


Wait-job -Id $Job.Id


}

if ((Test-Path -path $Tablet_folder_name)) {
$Job = Start-job -scriptblock {gi $Tablet_folder_name | .\Library\out-zip.ps1   
$backup_folder_name\tablet.zip $_} 


Wait-job -Id $Job.Id
```

}

This is my out.zip script

```
$path = $args[0]
$files = $input

write-output $path

if (-not $path.EndsWith('.zip')) {$path += '.zip'}   

if (-not (test-path $path)) { 
set-content $path ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
} 

$ZipFile = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($path) 
$files | foreach {$zipfile.CopyHere($_.fullname)}
```

while using the above script i am getting an error "Start-Job missing an argument for the paratmeter script block."
or is there another way so that i can put  a wait for these zips to finish one by one

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock .....
Wait-Job -Id $Job.Id
```

For the ScriptBlock error, try specifying the starting brace at the same line like:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
# Job code here 
}
```

Comment: where shall i specify the above code. in the backup script or in the main script which is calling the backup script]#

Comment: This is what i have written in my main scipt which is calling the backup script $Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {./Russia_Backup.ps1}
 Wait-Job -Id $Job.Id    but its not creating the backup

Comment: No error message, its says job completed but it doesnot create the backup folder, i am going to modify the new script in my question if you can have a read,

Comment: Have you tried running your back up script without AsJob and checked if it works that way.

Comment: I am calling the above backup script from my main script using this line of code  ./Russia_backup.Ps1

Comment: I meant out-zip file. Have you tried to run it separately to check if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57399/discussion-between-nadeem-and-user3770612).

Comment: basically what i am trying to achieve from my main script is to restore the admin and tab folder from the latest backup, the flow of my script is, it firsts backups up admin and tab folder it than deletes the current admin and tab folder than from previous backup it copies the content of the folders and paste on to admin, but i am stuck at initial backup, as soon as i run ./Russia_backup.ps1 from my main script the next block of code in the main script gets executed which is to delete the current admin and tab, thats what my prblem